# tired to add pagination on single category.php page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, categories

im tried to add pagination and set post per page on my  category.php page

how can i solve this
here  need set post per page and also pagination

here is my code for category.php

thanks

```
<?php if( have_posts() ): ?>
                <div class="cat-bread-cumb overflow-fix">
                    <u>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><span>/</span><?php the_archive_title(); ?></li>
                    </u>
                </div>

            <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <?php the_title( sprintf('<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h1>' ); ?>
                        <small>Posted on: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>, in <?php the_category(); ?></small>
                    </header>

                    <div class="row">

                        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>

                        <?php else: ?>

                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>

                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                </article>

            <?php endwhile; ?>



            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: use this plugin or add bottom code for pagination wordpress.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

Comment: thanks for suggestion but is not working

Comment: I need 1ts set post per page